# YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: while scanning for the next token found character '\t' that cannot start any token in "<reader>"

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-6

I'm trying to upload my Laravel project to elastic beanstalk. I've added MySQL on the server.

I created a `.ebextensions/init.config`:

```
container_commands:
    01initdb: 
        command: "php artisan migrate"
    02initdb
        command: "php artisan db:seed"
```

Now, I'm getting this error:

> Unable to deploy application version: The configuration file .ebextensions/init.config in application version cbt-source-10 contains invalid YAML or JSON. YAML exception: Invalid Yaml: while scanning for the next token found character '\t' that cannot start any token in "", line 2, column 1: 01initdb: ^ , JSON exception: Invalid JSON: Unexpected character (c) at position 0.. Update the configuration file.

Just for more reference I also added these things:

**database.php**

```
define('RDS_HOSTNAME', $_SERVER['RDS_HOSTNAME']);
define('RDS_USERNAME', $_SERVER['RDS_USERNAME']);
define('RDS_PASSWORD', $_SERVER['RDS_PASSWORD']);
define('RDS_DB_NAME', $_SERVER['RDS_DB_NAME']);
//in connections array
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
    'host' => RDS_HOSTNAME,
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => RDS_DB_NAME,
    'username' => RDS_USERNAME,
    'password' => RDS_PASSWORD,
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => true,
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
    'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
        PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
    ]) : [],
],
```

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function register()
{
   Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

I've also run the command `zip -d nameofyourzipfile.zip __MACOSX/\*`

I understand that I could probably just SSH into elastic beanstalk and some how and run the artisan commands after the project is deployed, but at this moment I'm just trying to learn elastic beanstalk. I'm probably a lot better off running the commands, b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message "Invalid Yaml" helps here. By the looks of it you're missing a single colon after 02initdb

So the YAML should look like

```
container_commands:
  01initdb: 
    command: "php artisan migrate"
  02initdb:
    command: "php artisan db:seed"
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The error message is because of there must be tabs in your config files convert it to spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the semicolons are appropriately placed after each key and avoid using tabs; instead, use spaces to indent:

[image]